# Rendering multi series line chart with time on x axis in AnyChart

Tags: data-visualization, anychart

I am trying Anychart line chart with multi series with date time on x axis. Not able to render the chart perfectly. Its drawing the series 1 with the given data then for the second series its rendering the date time freshly on x axis after the 1st series values then plotting the series 2.

data is like:

```
"data": [
  {"x": "10/2/2016 01:00:00 AM", "value": "128.14"},
  {"x": "10/2/2016 01:10:00 AM", "value": "112.61"}
]
  },{
// second series data
"data": [
      {"x": "10/2/2016 01:01:00 AM", "value": "90.54"},
      {"x": "10/2/2016 01:02:00 AM", "value": "104.19"},
      {"x": "10/2/2016 01:11:00 AM", "value": "150.67"}
]
```

It has to plot on x axis like 10/2/2016 01:00:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:01:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:02:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:10:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:11:00 AM

but it plotting like 10/2/2016 01:00:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:10:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:01:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:02:00 AM, 10/2/2016 01:11:00 AM

Updating the code:

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {
// JSON data
  var json = {
    // chart settings
    "chart": {
      // chart type
      "type": "line",
      // chart title
      "title": "Axes settings from JSON",
      // series settings
      "series": [{
        // first series data
        "data": [
          {"x": "10/2/2016 01:00:00 AM", "value": 128.14},
          {"x": "10/2/2016 01:10:00 AM", "value": 112.61},
          {"x": "10/3/2016 01:00:00 AM", "value": 12.14},
          {"x": "10/3/2016 01:10:00 AM", "value": 152.61},
        ]},{
        "data": [
          {"x": "10/2/2016 01:09:00 AM", "value": 28.14},
          {"x": "10/2/2016 01:11:00 AM", "value": 12.61},
          {"x": "10/3/2016 01:01:00 AM", "value": 1.14},
          {"x": "10/3/2016 01:12:00 AM", "value": 15.61},
        ]
      }],
            // x scale settings
      "xScale": {
        ticks: 
{scale: "DateTime"}
      },

xAxes: [{
title: "Basic X Axis"
  }],
      // chart container
      "container": "container"
    }
  };

  // get JSON data
  var chart = anychart.fromJson(json);

  // draw chart
  chart.draw();
});
```

Comment: Do you use datetime scale? Can you share the full listing on jsfiddle?

Comment: I have added the code which i tried with scale options too. It was very hard to find the details of scalling using json format in documentation. all the examples are using xml in the documentation.

Comment: Anything else needed? I tried in all the ways but no luck. atleast point me to the documentation or some examples with json.

Comment: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WebDev81/3ewcnp5j/1/) link for the anychart demo using date time on x axis

Answer (score 0):

With this type of data you need to use scatter chart: http://docs.anychart.com/7.12.0/Basic_Charts_Types/Scatter_Chart

Datetime scale should be set like this in JSON:

```
"xScale": {
type: "datetime",
minimum: "10/02/2016 00:00:00",
maximum: "10/03/2016 12:00:00",
}
```

Here is a sample: https://jsfiddle.net/3ewcnp5j/102/